# Mat tab switching on custom button click

Tags: mat-table

I have 3 tabs I am using mat-tab for tab switching. Now I need to switch to another tab on the custom button click instead of clicking on the tab. Does anyone have solution for this?

My code:

```
 <mat-tab  (click)="getTimeline()" label="Timeline">
        <div class="title2">
           <h1> Timeline for {{Traincode}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="timeheight">
        <div class="timeline" *ngIf="timelinearray.length!=0">
           <table id="headings" style="width:100%" >
              <tr>
                 <th style="text-align: left;padding-left: 42px;color:#4aaec5;width: 237px">Date</th>
                 <th style="text-align: left;color:#4aaec5;">Location</th>
              </tr>
           </table>
           <div class="entry" *ngFor="let data of timelinearray  " style="margin-top: 70px">
              <div class="title">
                 <h3>{{data.timestamp}} ,</h3>
                 <h4>&nbsp;{{data.assetcode}}</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="body">
                 <p>{{data.location}}</p>
                 <ul>
                    <li>Speed :{{data.speed}} m/s</li>
                    <li>Temperature :{{data.Temperature}} C</li>
                    <li>Vibration :<span *ngIf="data.status==='Pass'" style="color: #4cac77;">Normal</span><span *ngIf="data.status==='Fail'" style="color: red">Dangerous</span></li>
                    <li>Battery :{{data.Battery}} %</li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
     </mat-tab>
```

Now if i click  on the div

if I click on scroll to div tab should be switched

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Thank you

(click)="selectedIndex=2"